# SELECT field options disappear when saving widget

Tags: widgets, options, select, customization

I'm having an interesting problem that I can't seem to solve.

While creating a widget, I have created a select field with options that can be chosen on the widget screen. It all works perfectly fine, except when I save the widget, all of the options in the select field vanish. They all come back, with my chosen option saved, as soon as I refresh.

The code for each of the select options looks like this:

`foreach ($posttypes as $option) {
    echo '<option id="' . $option->name . '"', $posttype == $option->name ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option->name, '</option>';
}`

In this case, $posttypes is an array of post types.

When the select fields are rendered, they look like this:

`<select name="option-name" id="option-name">
<option value="option-value">Option Value</option>
<option value="option-value">Option Value</option>
<option value="option-value">Option Value</option>
</select>`

Any ideas why they would vanish like this?

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: My select options look like this: `foreach ($posttypes as $option) {
 echo '<option id="' . $option->name . '"', $posttype == $option->name ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option->name, '</option>';
}
`

Comment: How does the select field look like? Does it have the same `name` field as the option name?

Comment: Once rendered, the select form looks like this:

 `<select name="option-name" id="option-name"><option value="option-value">Option Value</option><option value="option-value">Option Value</option><option value="option-value">Option Value</option></select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. There was an extra closing slash on the opening select field.

Comment: just add the same annoying problem, and your answer got me looking for the same thing which solved it +1

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one afflicted with blindness ;)